# Creating web form sometimes results in Partial Class rather than Public class for code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've realized that some of the code behind pages in my project are Partial classes but some are declared as Public Class all the pages are created the same way in Visual Studio 2010.
(Right Click folder -> Add -> New Item -> Web Form)

Is there any reasoning why sometimes it creates a Partial class over a Public Class, and could this cause any issues with the environment or the end product.

### Partial Class Example

This is one of the pages that created as a partial class

#### Codebehind

```
Partial Class invParley
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private UsrProfile As New cBasicProfile
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

#### Front Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="invParley.aspx.vb" Inherits="Platform.invParley" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
```

### Public Class Example

This is what most of the pages look like and this is what new pages seem have

#### Codebehind

```
Public Class propNotAvail
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private UsrProfile As New cBasicProfile
```

#### Front Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="propNotAvail.aspx.vb" Inherits="Platform.propNotAvail" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.master" %>
```

Comment: refer this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/71494/why-use-partial-classes

Comment: Thanks for the link, Is there a reason why most times VS2010 creates a Web Form with Public Class and only sometimes uses Partial I feel like I'm missing something here. Thanks